# Docker from debian:wheezy cannot build

Tags: docker, debian, apt-get

Recently all my docker containers `FROM debian:wheezy` can not be built anymore.

I tried to launch the following command and even that did not work.

```
~ docker run -it --rm debian:wheezy /usr/bin/apt-get update

E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http received a segmentation fault.
```

Here is my docker version

```
~ docker -v
Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d18021e
```

Everything was working fine until last week but now I cannot build any of my wheezy containers. Using **debian:jessie** works but that's not the answer.

I tried to remove and reinstall docker, removing the **/var/lib/docker** folder, I removed all my containers and images, upgrade my distrib ...

Any idea of what is happening?

Ho, I'm using debian stretch

`uname -a 
Linux debtim 4.8.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.7-1 (2016-11-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Here is my `docker-compose build` result

```
docker-compose build
Building site_dev
Step 1 : FROM debian:wheezy
 ---> 26f8900cfb86
Step 2 : RUN echo 'hello world'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 14548f7351d2
Step 3 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 9b304362ffc8
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http received a segmentation fault.
ERROR: Service 'site_dev' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

and here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:wheezy
RUN echo 'hello world'    
RUN apt-get update
```

tim

Comment: Can you paste the output of the `docker build`?

Comment: docker build and dockerfile added in the description

Comment: maybe related to https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-debian/issues/55

Comment: I saw this conversation and followed to https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/28705#issuecomment-262226229 but I don't know how to solve the problem. I tried to change ```CONFIG_LEGACY_VSYSCALL_EMULATE``` and ```CONFIG_LEGACY_VSYSCALL_NONE``` and reboot but nothing changed...

Comment: According to the post it's directly related to the kernel version, is updating it an option?

Comment: Updating docker and my system has been one of my first steps to try to fix the problem. It didn't fix anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133326/discussion-between-tim-and-todea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everything lead to the conclusion that it is really a Kernel related issue as stated in https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/28705#issuecomment-262226229
I decided to downgrade my Debian Jessie to stable.
Everything works since. I have now the following .

```
sudo uname -a
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1 (2016-12-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
docker -v
Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most of the time happening after a kernel update on the host. downgrading or moving to a LTS version of the host kernel fixes it.

Yes, the symptom is when you build a Dockerfile:

```
   E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
   E: Sub-process http received a segmentation fault.
```

or when suddenly it is not possible to attach to docker VM using "docker exec -it"